# Generated parsers in Anorm

Tags: scala, anorm

I am just trying to implement generated parser in scalaAnorm.

My code is something like this ...

```
def selectExample(): Unit = {
case class memberInfo(member_id: BigInt, first_name: String,last_name:String)
import anorm.{ Macro, RowParser }
import anorm._
val barParser : RowParser[memberInfo] = Macro.indexedParser[memberInfo]
//val parser: RowParser[memberInfo] = Macro.namedParser[memberInfo]

val result1: List[memberInfo] = SQL"""SELECT * FROM cdsa.\"member\"""".as(barParser.*)

println("List Size : "+result1.size)
}
```

Reference : https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm

But I am getting compilation error and error is

```
[error] scala.ScalaReflectionException: <none> is not a method
[error]         at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi$class.asMethod(Symbols.scala:228)
[error]         at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asMethod(Symbols.scala:84)
[error]         at anorm.Macro$.parserImpl(Macro.scala:70)
[error]         at anorm.Macro$.offsetParserImpl(Macro.scala:38)
[error]         at anorm.Macro$.indexedParserImpl(Macro.scala:46)
[error]     val barParser : RowParser[memberInfo] = Macro.indexedParser[memberInfo]
```

Can one help me out to find out what is wrong in my code or any detail reference link where I can get the full implementation.

Comment: It's generally useful to indicate the version. Also try not to have the case class inside the def as a local decl (which is btw generally useless)

Answer (score 1):

Declare your case class outside method definition.